# How to add all unknown words by Code Spell Checker to dictionary or ignore them when language is another than english?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code

I am using Code Spell Checker (streetsidesoftware.code-spell-checker) VSC extension to check spelling, but I get warning for a lot of words because the ReactJS app interface is in another language than english.

For every word I can add it to the user or workspace dictionary, but for many words this is a pain and I want the "PROBLEMS" tab in VSC to show 0 errors/warnings/info before deploy.

How can I solve this issue ?

Comment: There are many Code Spell Checker extensions supporting different languages. [Check out this link](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=code%20spell%20checker&target=VSCode&category=All%20categories&sortBy=Relevance) and see whether your language is found on the list.

Answer (score 6):

If the project is in another language, as @AnsonH [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66885208/how-to-add-all-unknown-words-by-code-spell-checker-to-dictionary-or-ignore-them#comment118232450_66885208) you can install dictionaries in other languages.

Alternatively, you can run [`cspell-cli`](https://github.com/streetsidesoftware/cspell-cli) to return all of the unknown words so that you can copy and paste them into `cSpell.words` in your `settings.json`:

`npx cspell-cli "src/**/*.{json,ts,tsx}" --words-only --unique --no-progress`

Answer (score 0):

1. You can find all words you need and add them into your **settings.json** file.
2. You can add another spell checker extension with correct language.

Comment: The question is *how* to "find all the words you need"